# Sign of the Yang-Mills Field Strength Tensor

Tags: gauge-theory, conventions, yang-mills

My question is related to the definition of the field strength tensors in Gauge Theories. In some of the books I find the following definition for the components

$$F_{\mu \nu}^a=\partial_\mu A_\nu^a-\partial_\nu A_\mu^a + gf^{abc}A_\mu^bA_\nu^c$$

and in some books

$$F_{\mu \nu}^a=\partial_\mu A_\nu^a-\partial_\nu A_\mu^a - gf^{abc}A_\mu^bA_\nu^c.$$

On what does the sign in front of the coupling constant depend on? Does it depend on the space-time I am working on (Minkowski vs. Euclidean)? I am considering here only pure Yang-Mill theory, no matter fields are involved.

Comment: The field strength is simply the curvature, so for whatever conventions you pick to define the commutator of the generators of the group in question, use Cartan's equation to find the curvature. It also depends on the normalisation convention you pick for forms.

Comment: In the end I would like to calculate $F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu}$ to one loop order in perturbation theory and the sign of g will play a role in the calculation of the 3-point function. Unforunately, I am not defining any forms.

Comment: What precisely are you calculating? $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ sandwiched inside some Green's function/correlator?

Comment: You can just use Peskin and Schroeder's conventions, outlined in the appendix, with the corresponding Feynman rules.

Comment: Yes basically $<F²>$. The problem is that in my caluclations I have additional 3-point and 4-point gauge interactions in addition to the usual ones with new Feynman rules.  Somehow if I use the sing + infront of g i get funny results, whereas - sign gives a correct one. But the thing is I am not sure in which case I can choose the - sign I mean it is not enough to say it makes the result look nice. I didn't know what influences the sign. Sorry if the questions are stupid but its something that we didnt cover in any of the QFT curses.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which books?

Comment: @Dtzm In the end you can expand the Lagrangian for any sign and factors of $i$ and derive the Feynman rules by functional differentiation. What is important is consistency: pick a convention which is the same for the way you define the action of the gauge group, and the definition of the structure constants.

Comment: @JamalS thank you for your help. I realized that the quantity $F^2$ does not depenend on which sign you choose as long as you are consistent with your choice, as you pointed that out.  You can always absorb the minus sign in the definition of the coupling constant. This of course will change  the Feynman rules for the 3-gauge interaction by a sign which at the end  will yield the same result as if one would choose the + sign.